# Maximum of a list by an index

Tags: python, list

My lists are :

```
ptotal: [13545.75, 13009.5, 13009.5, 13009.500000000002]

backk1: [0, 11.5, 25.8, 39.0, 39.0, 39.0, 25.8, 11.5, 0, 11.5, 25.8, 39.0, 39.0, 0, 24.8, 24.7, 24.7, 24.7, 0, 24.7, 24.7, 24.7, 39.0, 39.0, 39.0]
```

I would like to find maximum value of list "ptotal" and its corresponding value in list "backk1". I have the following cod as a part of my whole program. It does not work well. Could you please help me?

```
ptotalfinal=max(ptotal) 

ptotalindex= max(enumerate(ptotal),key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
etaunk1max= (x in enumerate(zip(backetaunk1, ptotal),key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: So, you want to find the index of the maximum value of `ptotal` and then look up `backk1[index]`?

Comment: So, `backk1[ptotal.index(max(ptotal))]`?

Comment: In your example, you compute `ptotalindex`. If I may ask... Why? You do not use it at all...

Comment: _"...maximum value of list "ptotal" and **its corresponding value in list** "backk1""_ What is a "corresponding value"? How do you define/construct a correspondence between the values of two (possibly of different length) lists?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, it works thank you!

Comment: *"It does not work well."*? Could you be less specific?

Answer (score 0):

This would be my suggestion for finding the index of the max in a list because it only iterates once over the list, perhaps someone needs to convert this to C code and suggest it to the Python devs

```
def max_index(l):
    mx = float("-inf")
    idx = None
    for i,e in enumerate(l):
        if e > mx:
            mx = e
            idx = i
    return idx

ptotal = [13545.75, 13009.5, 13009.5, 13009.500000000002]
backk1 = [0, 11.5, 25.8, 39.0, 39.0, 39.0, 25.8, 11.5, 0, 11.5, 25.8, 39.0, 39.0, 0, 24.8, 24.7, 24.7, 24.7, 0, 24.7, 24.7, 24.7, 39.0, 39.0, 39.0]

number = backk1[max_index(ptotal)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has got many added functionalities which makes this task very simple. `max` gives the maximum value and `index` gives the index value of the maximum which can be used to find the corresponding element in `backk1`.

```
backk1[ptotal.index(max(ptotal))]
```